Spring boot 3 Drools 9.44.0.Final kieBuilder failing with Sisu : Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager
I'm integrating drools with spring boot 3 app running on java17, but while running the app kieBuilder.buildAll() is failing with exception
Sisu : Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager

What I Have Tried
Verified that the required Drools dependencies are included in the pom.xml.
Made sure the Drools .drl file is in the classpath.
Checked if there is a compatibility issue with Java 17, Spring Boot 3, or Drools 9.44.0.Final.
Tried running mvn clean install to ensure that dependencies are properly resolved.
Below is my drools java config
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class DroolDataSourceConfig {

  @Bean(name = "conditionalKieContainer")
  public KieContainer createConditionalKieContainer() {
    return createKieContainer("abc.drl");
  }

  private KieContainer createKieContainer(String droolsFilePath) {
    log.info("init Kie Container");
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(droolsFilePath, "UTF-8"));
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();
    return kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
  }
}

POM dependecies
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company.program</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-program</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>test-program</name>
    <description>Project for Tesgt</description>
    <modules>
        <module>child-common</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.apache.maven.plugins>3.13.0</org.apache.maven.plugins>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.30</org.projectlombok.version>
        <version.strati.boms>11.1.2</version.strati.boms>
        <version.logging>5.5.0</version.logging>
        <version.metrics>4.5.0</version.metrics>
        <version.txn.marking>4.8.1</version.txn.marking>
        <version.slf4j>1.7.4</version.slf4j>
        <azure.spring.data.cosmos.version>5.3.0</azure.spring.data.cosmos.version>
        <ccm.client.version>3.2.1</ccm.client.version>
        <version.sppotless.maven.plugin>2.26.0</version.sppotless.maven.plugin>
        <version.google.Java.Format>1.17.0</version.google.Java.Format>
        <wfs.kafka.version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</wfs.kafka.version>
        <versio.graphql.webclient>1.0.0</versio.graphql.webclient>
        <version.commons.collections4>4.4</version.commons.collections4>
        <version.openapi.swagger>2.5.0</version.openapi.swagger>
        <version.kafka.streams>2.2.1</version.kafka.streams>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>${version.kafka.streams}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-data-cosmos</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.spring.data.cosmos.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--openAPI-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${version.openapi.swagger}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openapitools/jackson-databind-nullable -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-extended-scalars</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        retry-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        drools dependencies    -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>9.44.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>9.44.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-mvel</artifactId>
            <version>9.44.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.44.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>9.44.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.sppotless.maven.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <java>
                        <googleJavaFormat>
                            <version>${version.google.Java.Format}</version>
                            <style>GOOGLE</style>
                        </googleJavaFormat>
                    </java>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--            sonar-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <ccm.configs.dir>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/tunr</ccm.configs.dir>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>${apache.maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>${org.apache.maven.plugins}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

